# Concatenate two List in a 2D Array in Python with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, i have 2 list that i want to concatenate with numpy. For now, i'm tring to do something like this :

`LeGraphiqueMatLab = np.array([LesDatesMatLab, LeGraphique], dtype=np.float64)`

But it gives me an error saying : "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 2) + inhomogeneous part."

Do I need to use np.array on each list first and then try to add them ?

Thanks

Comment: Tell us about the 2 lists.  `np.array(...,float)` tries to make a n-d array of floats.  The two inputs have to be matching size arrays (or lists that can be made into such).  Do `np.array(LesDatesMatlab)` and tell us the shape and dtype.  Same for `LeGraphiique`.  The name suggests one of this comes from a MATLAB matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) like that:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [5, 6]
np.concatenate((a, b))

#output
array([1, 2, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

As Phoenix stated, you can use [np.concatenate()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html); however, I have a feeling that LesDatesMatLab & LeGraphique may have different shapes as the error stated "inhomogeneous".

Without seeing what LesDatesMatLab & LeGraphique are, it's hard to say but try Phoenix's answer - if error persists, use LesDatesMatLab[.shape](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) & LeGraphique[.shape](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) to check if the shapes are both consistent. If not, you may need to use [np.reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to make them consistent.